# how to pass the id of a row link to a jquery , in order to use ajax?

Tags: php, jquery

how to pass the id of an edit or delete link via jquery in order to use ajax and php ?
here's my code at the front-end which displays the links

```
foreach($cat->getCategories() as $key => $val){
        echo $val."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='editcat' href=edit.php?id=".$key.">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='deletecat' href=delete.php?id=".$key.">Delete</a><br />";
}
```

now how to pass those id's to the jquery ?

```
   $('#editcat').click(function(){

   });

   $('#deletecat').click(function(){

   });
```

Comment: With your PHP code you will get a set of links which would have identical IDs, that is wrong

Comment: that is right, he needs same id for editing and deleting that particular row.

Comment: having identical IDs in HTML is wrong, in any way

Answer (score 0):

Put the value of the $key into a rel tag, `<a href='' rel='".$key."'>Edit</a>`

And then use this in the function

```
$('#editcat').click(function(){    
   var id = $(this).attr("rel");    
});
```

Comment: let's say i wanna add an alert, before the ajax call? should i place the alert at the bottom of the var id line, and then add a return false ? ..then followed by the ajax ?

Comment: Of course, but if you place a return false before the ajax code then it will never fire it.

Comment: the firebug console says, missing formal parameter
[Break On This Error] $('#deletecat').click(function(this){

Comment: Had to remove `this` parameter from the `function()` call. Try now with my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your foreach like this:

```
foreach($cat->getCategories() as $key => $val){
        echo $val."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='editcat' href=edit.php?id=".$key.">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='deletecat' href=delete.php?id=".$key.">Delete</a><br />";
        echo "<input type="hidden" id="key" value=".$key." />";
}
```

Now in JS:

```
   $('#editcat').click(function(){
        var key = $('#key').val();
   });

   $('#deletecat').click(function(){
        var key = $('#key').val();
   });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: there still will be several 'edicat' and 'delecat' id by page (one by category)

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP, you must have *unique ids* on the markup.

```
foreach($cat->getCategories() as $key => $val){
        echo $val."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='editcat_.$key' class="editcat" href=edit.php?id=".$key.">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id='deletecat_.$key' class='deletecat' href=delete.php?id=".$key.">Delete</a><br />";
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$('.editcat').click(function(){
    var id = (($(this).attr('id')).split('_', 2))[1];
    // do your other stuff here...
});

$('.deletecat').click(function(){
    var id = (($(this).attr('id')).split('_', 2))[1];
    // do your other stuff here...
});
```